# Как сделать выбор локации Unity Photon Pun 2?

Tags: c#, unity3d, разработка-игр

При вводе текста в inputfield в scroll view создается префаб кнопки и игрока перекидывает на локацию location_1. Другие игроки в лобби могут могут нажать на эту кнопку и перейти на созданный сервер.

Как сделать чтобы можно было выбрать локацию для создания сервера, например location_1 или location_2?

```
using UnityEngine; 
using Photon.Pun; 
using Photon.Realtime; 
using UnityEngine.UI; 
using System.Collections.Generic; 
 
public class Connection : MonoBehaviourPunCallbacks 
{ 
    [SerializeField] InputField RoomName; // inputfield 
    [SerializeField] ListItem itemPrefab; //префаб кнопки 
    [SerializeField] Transform content; //положение itemprefab в scroll view 
 
    List<RoomInfo> allRoomsInfo = new List<RoomInfo>(); 
 
    void Start() 
    { 
        PhotonNetwork.ConnectUsingSettings(); 
    } 
 
    public override void OnConnectedToMaster() 
    { 
        Debug.Log("Вы подключились к: " + PhotonNetwork.CloudRegion); 
        if(!PhotonNetwork.InLobby) 
            PhotonNetwork.JoinLobby(); 
    } 
 
    public void CreateRoomButton() //создание комнаты
    { 
        if(!PhotonNetwork.IsConnected) 
        { 
            return; 
        } 
 
        RoomOptions roomOptions = new RoomOptions(); 
        roomOptions.MaxPlayers = 5; 
        PhotonNetwork.JoinOrCreateRoom(RoomName.text, roomOptions, TypedLobby.Default); 
        PhotonNetwork.LoadLevel("location_1"); 
    } 
 
    public override void OnRoomListUpdate(List<RoomInfo> roomList) //обновление списка комнат
    { 
        foreach(RoomInfo info in roomList) 
        { 
            ListItem listItem = Instantiate(itemPrefab, content); 
 
            if(listItem != null) 
            { 
                listItem.SetInfo(info); 
                allRoomsInfo.Add(info); 
            } 
        } 
    } 

    public void JoinButton() //метод для itemPrefab для подключения к уже существующему серверу 
    { 
        PhotonNetwork.JoinRoom(RoomName.text); 
    } 
}
```